# Calculating quadratic polynomial, from linear interpolation of its coefficients

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms

I have a polynomial $xt^2 + yt + z$ that I want to evaluate for some value $t$. $t$ is always between 0 and 1.

But I cannot access the values $x$, $y$ and $z$ directly. Instead I can only access linear interpolated values between them:

- $A(\alpha) = x\alpha + y(1 - \alpha)$
- $B(\beta) = y\beta + z(1 - \beta)$
- $C(\gamma) = x\gamma + z(1 - \gamma)$

The arguments $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ need to be derived from $t$, and be between 0 and 1.

Is there any way algebraically to calculate $xt^2 + yt + z$, using only **two** of these values $A(\alpha)$, $B(\beta)$, $C(\gamma)$?

It is for a CUDA program, that may use the GPU's linear texture interpolation, to evaluate this polynomial using only 2 instead of 3 memory lookups.

Comment: What is the range of $t$?

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 t is between 0 and 1 always, added it to the post

Comment: Do you have access to $t$?

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 Yes $t$ is known

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $\alpha = 1$, $\beta = 1-1/(t+1)$.  Consider

$$t^2 A(\alpha) + (t+1)B(\beta) = t^2 x + (t+1)[y(1-1/(t+1)) + z(1/(1+t))] = xt^2 + yt + z.$$